# Blend SDK could not be found

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, .net-4.5, blend

I've tried to use in my WP 8.1 project my own fonts. I've found out that I should check the `Embed` property in Blend to do it, but the function is disabled and the message says:

> "This control is disabled because the Blend SDK could not be found".

I've searched on this site https://www.nuget.org/packages/Expression.Blend.Sdk/ . It says that is for 8.1 version, but the log says something different:

> "You are trying to install this package into a project that targets WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework."

I've also found out that there's a Expression Blend Software Development Kit (SDK) available to download but only for .NET 4.0. What should I do to solve this problem? I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Professional.